# I am not able to add product in cart after first payment done

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have one magento store all this thinks working well , First time add to cart working well with successfully checkout and payment done. After I want to add another product in my cart that time I am not able to add any product in my cart , After logout and login again its working well , But after payment done I am not able to add product in cart. I am search a lot  but cant get success. Please help me to short out this issue . I am using magento 1.8.0.0

Error message :

```
a:5:{i:0;s:313:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`intercon_2Einter`.`sales_flat_quote_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_ITEM_QUOTE_ID_SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `sales_flat_quote` (`entity_id`) ON DE)";i:1;s:4159:"#0 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#4 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#5 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#6 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('sales_flat_quot...', Array)
#7 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item))
#8 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php(735): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/code/local/Ajax/ProductAdjust/Model/Observer.php(92): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item->save()
#10 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Ajax_ProductAdjust_Model_Observer->updatePrice(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Ajax_ProductAdjust_Model_Observer), 'updatePrice', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_quote_add...', Array)
#13 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(942): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_add...', Array)
#14 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1083): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->addItem(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item))
#15 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(992): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->_addCatalogProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), '1')
#16 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1046): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->addProductAdvanced(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Varien_Object), 'full')
#17 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(265): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->addProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Varien_Object))
#18 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/code/local/Softprodigy/Multipleaddtocart/controllers/AddController.php(89): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->addProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Array)
#19 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Softprodigy_Multipleaddtocart_AddController->checksingleAction()
#20 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('checksingle')
#21 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#22 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#23 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#24 /home/intercon/domains/dekabelexpert.nl/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#25
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be specifically programming related. It should be moved to https://magento.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

- inserting a product in the cart after a payment resulted in the mentioned SQL error
- inserting a product in a empty cart resulted in "empty cart" even though adding another product would result in a cart with both items set.

I narrowed it down to an observer I had on `sales_quote_item_set_product`. In this observer, I modified the QuoteItem (setting prices and adding options) and then I saved it. I think that the saving was causing the issue.

I moved the logic to the `sales_quote_save_after` event, and both errors disappeared. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while using `sales_quote_add_item` event observer. I was trying to edit product price programmatically while adding the product to cart.

I was saving quote item in my *Observer* class.

```
$quoteItem->save();
```

Later, I found out that we don't need to save quote item object because it gets saved automatically later on as it is passed by reference.

So, the solution was to remove/comment the line:

```
// $quoteItem->save();
```